# Looking to getting my money back from a scam

Tags: fraud

I was recently scammed by a company promising large returns using Bitcoin/FX trading. I hired someone to recoup my losses and they told me they had and sent photo proof that the money was in a cryptocurrency wallet. When I tried to withdraw the money, I was told I would have to deposit $300 worth of Bitcoin before I could withdraw my money. Is this a policy with cryptocurrency wallets or are they just trying to get more of my money? Thank you.